# Java Character check in a Switch-statement

Tags: java, char, switch-statement

So only a quick question here regarding a switch case with a char.

So:

```
char c = a.charAt(i);
    switch(c){
        case 'a': System.out.print("This is an a");
        case ''': System.out.print("How can one get this character checked in the case?);

}
```

So how can a case check for a letter ' when the style for checking the char in the case is ' ' ?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the single quote:

```
case '\''
```

Answer (score 4):

escape ' with \

example:

```
case '\'': System.out.print("How can one get this character checked in the case?);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 switch(c) {
        case 'a': 
               System.out.print("This is an a"); 
               break;
        case '\'': 
               System.out.print("How can one get this character checked in the case?);
               break;
   }
```

note that `break` is necessary, without if if c=='a' the program will fall thru to the next case and print the second line too. Note that though the second break is unnecessary but is considered a good style.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your single quote character like this:

```
    case '\''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With This

```
char c = a.charAt(i);
    switch(c){
        case 'a': {
                    System.out.print("This is an a");
                    break;
                   }
        case '\'': System.out.print("How can one get this character checked in the case?);
}
```